# Perl web serving with nginx and FastCGI - not able to read parameters

Tags: perl, nginx, cgi, fastcgi

There are any number of tutorials out there on how to use FastCGI to CGI wrappers to serve Perl code using nginx. But I'm comfortable working with Perl modules myself, so I don't need the wrapper. I'm trying to figure out the right way to set this up. Here's the code I have so far:

```
#!perl

use CGI;
use FCGI;

my $s = FCGI::OpenSocket(':9000',20);
my $r = FCGI::Request( \*STDIN, \*STDOUT, \*STDERR,
    \%ENV, $s);
while ($r->Accept >= 0) {
    my $cgi = CGI->new;
    print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
    print "<html><body>The foo input is ", $cgi->param('foo'), "</body></html>";
    $r->Finish;
}
```

And enable it in nginx like so:

```
location /foo {
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.pl;
}
```

The problem is that no matter how many times I call the script, `param` returns the same value that was passed the very first time it was called since starting the program. Is there a better way of doing this? I'm open to alternatives to `CGI.pm` as well.

Comment: Your posted code would have worked fine if you have instructed `CGI.pm` to clear it's global cache before you instantiated `CGI.pm`. `CGI::initialize_globals();`

Comment: Interesting. Didn't know about that one. I'll keep it in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CGI::Fast](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CGI%3a%3aFast) will handle most of the work for you, including setting up the daemon.

```
use CGI::Fast;

local $ENV{FCGI_SOCKET_PATH} = ":9000";
local $ENV{FCGI_LISTEN_QUEUE} = 20;

while ($q = CGI::Fast->new) {
    print $q->header;
    print "<html><body>The foo input is ", $cgi->param('foo'), "</body></html>";
}
```

An alternative is [Nginx::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Nginx%3a%3aSimple) which gives you more control over the behavior of your cgi-script-as-daemon.

Comment: Having some trouble with `CGI::Fast`. I tried running it on the command line, and it simply ran once and exited. So it doesn't seem to have listened to the port, or bound the stdio streams etc.

Comment: Got it working in the end, but there seems to be a documentation bug in `CGI::Fast` regarding environment variables, which I can report.