# How to report a CPAN module bug

Tags: perl, cpan, bug-reporting

Related to my recent question [Perl web serving with nginx and FastCGI - not able to read parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206323/perl-web-serving-with-nginx-and-fastcgi-not-able-to-read-parameters) I began using the module `CGI::Fast` and found what I'm fairly certain is a bug in it - could be a documentation bug rather than code, but either way. What's the best way to report this or at least inquire about it a somewhat official way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- Go to CPAN location for the module: http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CGI::Fast

  - On the right-hand side there's a little widget called "CPAN RT", with a link "[View/Report bugs](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=CGI)" (RT is a ticketing/issue tracking system used for CPAN)
  - Also, any module usually has "AUTHOR INFORMATION" POD section, which in this case explicitly states:

    > Address bug reports and comments to: lstein@cshl.org

Comment: As a rule of thumb, follow the instructions over defaulting to RT. If they don't say to use RT then I suggest ending the email with "Would you like me to add this to RT?"

Comment: Thanks for that pointer. Of course in this case it seems to mention a copyright of 1998 and an email address for an author who is no longer the current maintainer, but I'll see what I can do. :)

Comment: I'd say RT is more likely to get to an active maintainer than relying in the email address in the pods, when the latest release on CPAN is relatively new, as is true in this case. Most CPAN maintainers also really like it if you can build a Perl script to demonstrate the issue, or even better a test case (a *.t file) like those in the distribution on CPAN

Comment: The View/Report bugs link on search.cpan.org actually goes to the bugtracker indicated by the [module's metadata](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CPAN::Meta::Spec#resources).  RT is just the default value if the module's author didn't bother to indicate otherwise.